# Showing non-injectivity

Tags: banach-spaces, operator-theory

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and let $A:X\rightarrow Y$ be a linear operator. Does it suffice to show that there exists a sequence $x_n\in X$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Ax_n = 0$ with $||x_n||=1\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ to proof non-injectivity of $A$?

Comment: I don't think this is true. Let $X=Y$ both be a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Let $A:X\rightarrow X$ be the mapping where $A(e_{n})=e_{n}/n$. Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Ae_{n}=0$ in the topology given by $\|\cdot\|$ and clearly $\|e_{n}\|=1$ for $n\geq 1$. The mapping $A$ is injective. There are other examples like this one.

Comment: With that being said, if $A$ is a bijective bounded linear operator between Banach spaces, then the mapping $A$ is a homeomorphism (this is a consequence of the open mapping theorem for Banach spaces). You can use this fact to conclude that if $A:X\rightarrow Y$ is a surjective linear operator with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A x_{n}=0$ for some sequence $(x_{n})$ with $\|x_{n}\|=1$ for all $n$, then you know that $A$ cannot be injective.

Comment: @JosephVanName Thank you very much for the swift response! Your addendum might help me with my problem. I'm actually trying to show that some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ is in the spectrum of $A$ if I can show that $(\lambda I-A)x_n$ tends to 0 for non-zero $x_n$, which I hoped would have proven non-injectivity of $(\lambda I-A)$ and therefore non-bijectivity.

Comment: @JosephVanName Want to post this as an answer?

Comment: Saying $\lambda I-A$ is not injective says $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.  Saying $\lambda I - A$ is not invertible is saying $\lambda$ belongs to the spectrum of $A$.  Any discussion of spectrum in infinite-dimensional cases will have examples where the spectrum is more than merely the set of eigenvalues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are examples of Banach spaces $X,Y$ along with bounded linear mappings $L:X\rightarrow Y$ and sequences $(x_{n})_{n}$ of elements in $X$ such that
$^{\lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}L(x_{n})=0$ in the metric space induced by the norm on $Y$ but where $\|x_{n}\|=1$ for each $n$. For instance, if $X=Y$ and $X$ is a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_{n})_{n\geq 1}$, and
$A:X\rightarrow Y$ is the bounded linear operator defined by letting
$L(e_{n})=e_{n}/n$ for $n\geq 1$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}L(e_{n})=0$ in the metric topology induced by the norm, but $\|e_{n}\|=1$ for each $n$.

The open mapping theorem for Banach spaces states that if $X,Y$ are Banach spaces and $L:X\rightarrow Y$ is a surjective bounded linear mapping, then the mapping $L$ is an open mapping. As a consequence, if $X,Y$ are Banach spaces and $L:X\rightarrow Y$ is a bijective linear continuous mapping, then $L$ is a homeomorphism (i.e. $L^{-1}$ is also continuous). As a consequence, if $L:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous linear surjection between Banach spaces with where $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}L(x_{n})=0$ with respect to metric generated by the norm but where $\|x_{n}\|=1$ for each $n$, then the mapping $L$ cannot be injective.

Comment: If you’re trying to use this on a specific example, it’s worth noting that you can relax the condition on surjectivity to just require that the image is closed. There are quite a few results that give sufficient conditions for the image to be closed.